# AWS SNS When publish a message to a topic, is there any way to specify which protocol to use?

Tags: amazon-sns

Each subscription can have one and only one protocol

```
String topicArn = snsClient.createTopic(new CreateTopicRequest("lambda_topic" /*topic Name*/).getTopicArn();
String subscriptionArn = snsClient.subscribe(new SubscribeRequest(topicArn,"lambda", "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:messageStore"));
```

So when publishing a message to a topic, is there any way to specify which protocol to use so that I don't end up with sending messages to all protocols like this?

```
{
"default": "Message body text here.", 
"email": "Message body text here.", 
"sms": "Message body text here."
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html?

Comment: Yes. message filtering is about controlling which subscriber can receive the message. My question is about how to specify a protocol when I publish a message.